# random selection from array

Tags: java, android

I have this block of code below which is to control questions which are to be displayed from the array.
I am having problem with the the 3rd line of code, an i am not entirely sure what the problem is.

rnd1, rnd2 are both double. Eclipse is telling me that rnd2 should be an int. however i was advised that the rnd's should be double for the ceiling function to work.
ques is a text field. questions is the array.

```
 rnd1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
 rnd2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
 ques.setText(questions[rnd2]);
```

---

Im basing this on action script which i used for a quiz application.
It is used to pick out the question from the question array randomly.

```
rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
rnd2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
q.text=questions[rnd2];
if(questions[rnd2]=="x")
{
  change_question();
}
questions[rnd2]="x";
enable_disable(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select an element of an array with an `int` so make rnd2 an `int` and cast the ceiling function (if you really need it, if you cast just the random it'll truncate the decimal places off) like so:

```
rnd2 = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
```

Just make sure to declare rnd2 as an `int` not `double`

Comment: Thanks i have been taking a bit of a whack by some member for not trying in their opinion. Is thereny resources you would recommend looking at. Being a fairly new to java, it would be usefull to have a list of resources which have a good reputation and will be worth looking at. 
Thanks Again!

Comment: @KCCMan[Help straight from Oracle!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). It's really the best resource for beginners.